# Magento product save, how to detect whether product data has been changed

Tags: magento

While editting a product in the backend I need to know whether any of it's data has been changed or not?

$product->hasDataChanges() always return true even I didn't modify any fields.

Answer (score 5):

**Why does $product->hasDataChanges() always return true even I didn't modify any fields.?**

Looking into the Varien_Object function **setData** function it appears that **hasDataChanges** is always set to true even if technically the data has not changes.

```
public function setData($key, $value=null)
{
    $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
    if(is_array($key)) {
        $this->_data = $key;
        $this->_addFullNames();
    } else {
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
        if (isset($this->_syncFieldsMap[$key])) {
            $fullFieldName = $this->_syncFieldsMap[$key];
            $this->_data[$fullFieldName] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

**Solution:**

When you have a model which is an type of Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, then you can easily get the previous data (original data) on save using public function getOrigData($key=null) method.

**getOrigData()** returns the data in the object at the time it was initialized/populated.

After the model is initialised you can update that data and getData() will return what you currently have in that object.

Have a look at Varien_Object (getOrigData,setOrigData) so you can have a look at how and why it is used.

Comment: I know that is the issue(setting $this->_hasDataChanges = true without checking the change in data) why $product->hasDataChanges() always return true. I have tried to compare $product->getData() and $product->getOrigData() values. But its really tricky to compare those since they contain a lot of deep arrays and objects.